# Which controller the export hits

Tags: magento2, controllers, url

I'm trying to understand where the controller of export stock sources is being hitted

My url is the following `/admin/export/export/key/fjkzegjzehgjze/entity/stock_sources/file_format/csv`

The code seems to be the following

```
/**
 * Continue export process after filter settings
 *
 * return void
 */
getFile = function() {
    if ($('entity') && $F('entity')) {
        var form      = $('export_filter_form');
        var oldAction = form.action;
        var url = oldAction + ((oldAction.slice(-1) != '/') ? '/' : '') + 'entity/' + $F('entity')
            + '/file_format/' + $F('file_format');
        if ($F('fields_enclosure')) {
            url += '/fields_enclosure/' + $F('fields_enclosure');
        }
        if ($F('simplified_version')) {
            url += '/simplified_version/' + $F('simplified_version');
        }
        form.action = url;
        form.submit();
        form.action   = oldAction;
    } else {
        alert({
            content: 'Invalid data'
        });
    }
};

varienExport = new VarienExport();
//]]>
});</script>
```

But i'm not able to locate what file is being used to process all that.

I'm aiming a custom sorting of the collection but to do that i need to find the right controller

Thanks !

Comment: You can check that in network tab, after inspect go to network tab clear logs then click export you can check there which controller is htiting after click on export

Comment: @ArunSharma Don't get what you mean, i already know which url is sent after click on export (it's the one i pasted there). I just don't know which controller this url trigger. The network isn't telling me that, it's the frontname and url path that lead to the controller. But i can't get it there.

Comment: @Claims Did you check my answer?

Comment: @TuVan Had to change of topic but i will end up checking this eventually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The controller for all exports is `Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\Export`, locate in `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php`.

`stock sources` is the param of the export controller.